# Fragment popup (Custom View) translucent/transparent

Tags: android

I want know if exist the possibility of change background LinearLayout, that I pass to a AlertDialog.Builder.

I like how this :

header (image with background transparent)
and text of selections.

I'm can't use "android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" because I have only a activity.

I tried :

background="@null"

background="#80000000" -- And others

"android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"

And not change layout to transparent

Image : (sorry I'm not a Picasso )

Activity  - > calls - > Fragment - calls - > popup

[image]

Comment: Could you be more precies and clear, it is not clear what you are asking at all to me.

Comment: I updated, and I posted my image

Comment: I try change background but I can't do it, because not work any methods...

Answer (score 0):

You can create your dialog in a different way if the transparent don't work.

Create an activity that serve as popup/dialog:

```
<activity
    android:name="MyActivityPopup"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop" >
</activity>
```

Then activity_popup xml :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="600dp"
    android:layout_height="240dp"
    android:background="@color/white" >
```

The width/height create an activity with no contour. Then you can design your view as you want.

Finally, in MyActivityPopup class :

```
public class MyActivityPopup extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_popup);
    setFinishOnTouchOutside(false);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Sorry I don't have measure statics " 600x240" and also not use this method, I solved with a centerCrop (Image) and programatically I rest % height/3 respectively of the point  + hight (Material design (Remember that bar not count padding) ), but thanks